# Spring security - Is username and password must for creating authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I am using spring security to authenticate a user. The user is authenticated by a third party and will already be authenticated when he reaches my application.
To implemented this, I have simulated a Authentication object.

I don't have any username and password and instead just have identifier. I check if this identifier is valid or not using my custom code.

My query is as follows:

1. Do I require a username and password to create a authentication object.
   I have done without providing username and password and my application works fine.
2. I just want to ensure that I am using spring-security correctly.
3. Is there any impact of not putting username and password in Authentication object. I read below  in AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider:

   // Ensure we return the original credentials the user supplied,
   // so subsequent attempts are successful even with encoded passwords.

I have also implemented a custom provider.

1. What does above comments means?
2. Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 1):

The `Authentication` interface in Spring Security represents a token for carrying out validations against the configured security rules and the current call context. This interface has six methods of interest - `getPrincipal`, `getCredentials`, `getDetails`, `getAuthorities`, `isAuthenticated` and `setAuthenticated`.

Since you are authenticating users on your own, you should be mostly concerned with calling `setAuthenticated(true)` at an appropriate stage in the flow so that `isAuthenticated` starts returning `true` to indicate an authenticated user. Additionally, you may add `GrantedAuthority`s to the `Authentication` for any role-based checks to work correctly.

However, it will be useful to make sure that `getPrincipal` (username in the case of form login) returns a unique value per user or per session. This will prevent the possibility of user sessions getting interchanged due to non-unique principal, which is used by the framework to identify users uniquely.

You may leave `getCredentials` and `getDetails` unimplemented. In fact, `getCredentials` (password in the case of form login) should be left unimplemented in your case because your application does not have the credentials used to actually authenticate the user; plus, it is a security risk to keep the credentials around after the user has been authenticated successfully.

Comment: Hi Manish,   Thanks.   I have already done as above and my application is working fine. I asked as I am not an expert on security and thus wanted to confirm if my approach is correct or not.                                                             Is this above text referred from some spring security documentation. Also should getPrinciple() return the identifier I used for authenticating. The identifier is not username but a unique value for a particular user. I do not use form login in my case as I am not authenticating using username/password for the reason originally listed.

Comment: The details are from my experience of implementing custom `AuthenticationProvider`s and `AuthenticationFilter`s. Yes, you should use the authentication identifier as the principal, as long as it is unique per user or per session. This way your authentication tokens will not get messed up. Note that that if you use per-session identifiers, things such as concurrent session control and remember-me will not work out-of-the-box as they rely on per-user unique principals.